# eToken not detected

Tags: fedora, security, drivers, authentication

I want to use an `Aladdin eToken Pro 32k 4.2B` on Fedora 32 but it is not detected. It shows as another model in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0529:0600 Aladdin Knowledge Systems eToken Pro 64k (4.2)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0529 Aladdin Knowledge Systems
  idProduct          0x0600 eToken Pro 64k (4.2)
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0014
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  02 ff
```

[image]

`pcsc_scan` shows nothing and

```
$ opensc-tool -l
No smart card readers found.
```

On Windows it is immediately detected when inserted and a red led lights up. This is how it is shown on Windows `SafeNet Authentication Client`

[image]

I have SafeNet Client installed on Fedora but since the eToken is not detected it shows nothing.

`pcscd` is working:

```
$ systemctl status pcscd.service
● pcscd.service - PC/SC Smart Card Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/pcscd.service; indirect; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-25 15:22:06 -03; 2h 8min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pcscd.socket
       Docs: man:pcscd(8)
   Main PID: 1231 (pcscd)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 19088)
     Memory: 2.8M
        CPU: 682ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/pcscd.service
             └─1231 /usr/sbin/pcscd --foreground --auto-exit
```

My guess is that the wrong driver is being loaded. What is yours?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install latest version (SafenetAuthenticationClient-10.7.77-1.x86_64) and I got same error. So, I decided to downgrade to version 9.0.43. But, before instalation you need to run:

```
# dnf install compat-openssl10
```

For SACMonitor, I tried this workaround:

```
# bash -c 'cat > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gtk3.conf << 'EOF'
/usr/lib64/gtk-3.0/modules
EOF'
# ldconfig
```

However, I coudn't run SACTools or SACMonitor.